# Can slack bots use slack-api as admin or or full privileges user, using slack as guest?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

As a slack guest user I can not update the channels topic, what if I create a bot and use https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.setTopic ? will it be possible to update the topic or will it take my guest user for this and return error?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rights of a Slack app are defined by

- the requested scopes at installation (e.g. [`channels.write`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:write), which you need to change the channel topic).
- the rights of the installing user which are inherited (e.g. admin rights to delete messages)

So if you have a conversational bot that can be instructed to change the channel topic a guest user could use it and it would work.

Note that this will not work with slash commands though, since guest users can not use slash commands. (as described [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202518103-Multi-Channel-and-Single-Channel-Guests))

Answer (score 0):

As a guest user, you're unable to install applications, so you would require a regular user to install said app, and then the app would use their user token to update the topic.